# Spring boot 1.5.1 - Inside registered Filter can not access Spring context @Value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I could not read the below properties value, where as I can read the same value in to my other controllers But not in the furnished Filter

```
@Value("${session.timout.mins}")
    private String sessionTimeout;
```

### My Filter

```
@Configuration
public class AuthoriseFilter implements Filter {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthoriseFilter.class);

    private static String ADMIN_LOGIN_EMIAL = "sdsds@mail.com";
    private static String ISSUER_LOGIN_EMIAL = "dsds@mail.com";

    @Value("${session.timout.mins}")
    private String sessionTimeout;
```

### This is how Filter is registered inside Spring context

```
package com.digrec.config;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.digrec.filter.AuthenticateFilter;
import com.digrec.filter.AuthoriseFilter;

@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {

     @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean authoriseFilterRegistrationBean() {
            FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
            String[] patterns = new String[]{"/login", "/logout"};
            registrationBean.setName("authFilter");
            AuthoriseFilter authFilter = new AuthoriseFilter();
            registrationBean.setFilter(authFilter);
            registrationBean.addUrlPatterns(patterns);
            registrationBean.setOrder(1);
            return registrationBean;
        }

     @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean authenticateFilterRegistrationBean() {
            FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
            String[] patterns = new String[]{"/api/*", "/adminapi/*"};
            registrationBean.setName("authenticateFilter");
            AuthenticateFilter authFilter = new AuthenticateFilter();
            registrationBean.setFilter(authFilter);
            registrationBean.addUrlPatterns(patterns);
            registrationBean.setOrder(1);
            return registrationBean;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your FilterConfig.class you are creating the filter instances yourself by calling constructor. This should be done using spring managed bean like below. I'm showing only for AuthoriseFilter, similar should be done for AuthenticationFilter also.

```
@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean authoriseFilterRegistrationBean(@Autowired AuthoriseFilter authFilter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        String[] patterns = new String[]{"/", "/list"};
        registrationBean.setName("authFilter");
        registrationBean.setFilter(authFilter);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns(patterns);
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

And your filter isn't configuration so it should be annotated with @Component

```
@Component
public class AuthoriseFilter implements Filter {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthoriseFilter.class);

    private static String ADMIN_LOGIN_EMIAL = "sdsds@mail.com";
    private static String ISSUER_LOGIN_EMIAL = "dsds@mail.com";

    @Value("${session.timout.mins}")
    private String sessionTimeout;
}
```

Comment: There's no need for `@Autowired` on the argument of the `authoriseFilterRegistrationBean` method